# using button to increment divs in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, web, frontend

I am fairly new to React/Next and I had a quick question.

I am trying to create a button that will increment the number of divs in real time.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'


const Clown = () => {

    const [clownCounter, setClownCounter] = React.useState(1);

    function addClown(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
        <div>
            <form>
                 
                {Array.from({ length: clownCounter}, (_unused, index) => index + 1).map(
                    (clownIndex) => {
                        const clownid = `${clownIndex}`
                        return (
                        <div key={clownid } className="clown-box">
                            <label htmlFor={clownid }>Activity {clownIndex}</label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="text" onChange={(e)=> onChangeForm(e)} name={activityId} id={activityId} />
                            <br />
                        </div>
                        )
                    },
                )}
                <span className="clown-add">
                    <button onClick={addClown} onChange={() => { setClownCounter(clownCounter++) }}>Add Clown</button>
                </span>   
                <br />  
            </form>
        </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
export default Clown
```

As you can see the goal is to increase the amount of clown-box divs everytime the button is clicked. I think I am close but it is not currently working. Can anyone help?

Comment: `Array.from({ length: clownCounter}` isn't doing what you'd expect it would do.

Answer (score 1):

There are few small this wrong with your code.

First, you have an extra comma(,) after the return statement in map function

Second, you are updating state clownCounter on `onChange` event in button, which is incorrect. You should update it on click and also prevent the default behaviour of form submit on click of button or you can define the button type to be `type="button"`

Lastly, you need to define your onChangeForm function

```js
const Clown = () => {

    const [clownCounter, setClownCounter] = React.useState(1);
    
    function onChangeForm() {

    }

    function addClown(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        setClownCounter(prev=> prev+1);
    }
    
    console.log(clownCounter);
    return(
        <div>
            <form>
                 
                {Array.from({ length: clownCounter}, (_unused, index) => index + 1).map(
                    (clownIndex) => {
                        const clownid = `${clownIndex}`;
                        return (
                        <div key={clownid } className="clown-box">
                            <label htmlFor={clownid }>Activity {clownIndex}</label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="text" onChange={(e)=> onChangeForm(e)} name={'activityId'} id={'activityId'} />
                            <br />
                        </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
                <span className="clown-add">
                    <button type="button" onClick={addClown}>Add Clown</button>
                </span>   
                <br />  
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Clown />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>**Edit**: Thought issue was caused by `Array.from`, but, it's not. I've removed that part, but kept the example since OP might find it useful</sup>

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Clowns = ({ title }) => {
    const [clownCounter, setClownCounter] = React.useState(1);
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setClownCounter(clownCounter + 1)}>
                Add clown
            </button>
            <div className='clowns'>
                {Array.from({ length: clownCounter}, (_unused, index) => index + 1).map((e, i) => (
                    <div>
                        <h4>{`Clown #${i + 1}`}</h4>
                        <img src={`https://placehold.it/150x150&text=Clown%20%23${i + 1}`} />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Clowns />, document.getElementById("react") );
```

```css
.clowns { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
h4 { margin-bottom: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: `Array.from({ length: clownCounter}, (_unused, index) => index + 1)` returns an array with elements [1 to clownCounter]

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @ShubhamKhatri, new way for me.